# Touch event does not work in Kivy on the Waveshare HDMI screen(Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, touch, kivy, hdmi

I have attached the HDMI touchscreen from waveshare - https://www.waveshare.com/7inch-HDMI-LCD-C.htm

The touch event is working well on the Raspian Stretch, but does not work in the Kivy application.

Here is the output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 kivy/examples/demo/showcase/main.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-02-14_6.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-a4d93d6, 20180211
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'VideoCore IV HW'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not     docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
xclip version 0.12
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Kim Saunders et al.
Distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: xclip(['clipboard_dbusklipper',     'clipboard_gtk3'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <b'Logitech K400 Plus\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             '>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '> range ABS X position is 0 - 1024
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '> range ABS Y position is 0 - 600
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '> range ABS pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '> range position X is 0 - 1024
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '> range position Y is 0 - 600
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <b'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen\x00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                '> range pressure is 0 - 255
```

I tried to add input providers into `~/.kivy/config.ini` like this:

```
[input]
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Not sure what should be the `[input]` section.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this exact display and touchscreen. Although I am using buster on an rpi4.
I found that if the kivy app is run fullscreen with no decorations, then it works fine so long as the ONLY entry under [input] is

```
[input]
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
```

You basically will not be using the Xwindows input or the HID input.
Also make sure keyboard_mode = systemanddock under the [kivy] section.